# Passing data to the child component through ngx bootstrap modal function

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I have the following code in my Parent component in an angular application

**PARENT COMPONENT**

```
<div>
    <button *ngIf="data.type == 'el'" (click)="readInfo('el')">click</button>
    <button *ngIf="data.type == 'ga'" (click)="readInfo('ga')">click</button>
</div>


readInfo(type) {
    if (type === 'el') {
      this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ChildComponent, { class: 'modal-lg' }, el);
    } else if (type === 'ga') {
      this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ChildComponent, { class: 'modal-lg' }, ga);
    }
  }
```

**CHILD COMPONENT**

```
 <div class="container" *ngIf="el">
      <!-- el contents goes here -->
  </div>

  <div class="container" *ngIf="ga">
    <!-- ga contents goes here -->
</div>
```

i want to pass a value to the ChildComponent from my parent component through the modal function. My objective is to retrieve this value inside my ChildComponent and display contents based on it using *ngIf

Comment: What about using @Input to pass your data dynamically, you can check this link for more information: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Using callback to pass the data back to parent component, and pass it via component property to child component.

```
this.modalSvc.show(LoadGeneratorAddModalComponent, {
         initialState: {
            successCb: (data) => {
                // data come from the modal, assign it to your variable in parent component
                this.dataPassToChild = data;
            }
         }
      }
    );
```

**Solution 2**

You can always pass data via service, create a subject, and expose the observable in service.
You can observe the observable in the child component, and trigger the event in the modal component.